# How to send a particular field to External system Through API

Tags: rest-api, api, integration

I have a requirement to give an particular Field from salesforce custom object to external system through APi.

Note: The field is a Autonumber field

Can anyone provide any suggestion how we can achieve this.

Comment: Outbound message

Comment: @Eric so using outbount message we can send the field. Can the external system update this field in salesforce .